# What would happen if someone time travel far enough to the Big Bang?

Tags: time-travel

Imagine if someone can time travel any time and any where he/she wants, (Past,Present, & Future). But what if the time machine got out of control and took them to the big bang. What would happen to them?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a worldbuilding question. You seem to be asking about the conditions in the universe at (or just after) the big bang. Might be more suitable to ask on Physics SE, but if you want to know about conditions in the universe actually at the moment of the big bang, I suspect the answer is that we don't know.

Comment: Also, at the moment of the big bang, there wouldn't be a universe to be in.  So all physical laws are thrown out the window, and the answer is "practically anything, we have no way of knowing".  It's also worth noting that time travel _backwards_ is very likely impossible, so a physics-based answer is difficult.

Comment: @jdunlop Or perhaps time travel *forwards* to the next Big Bang.

Comment: You can make it a plot point that the runaway time machine was the cause of the Big Bang.

Comment: @Alexander Better yet: all time machines are runaway and every alien throughout all space-time who tried one collides at the same point: the Big Bang.

Answer (score 2):

Without being a physicist, I'd guess that you'd just instantaneously evaporate. The forces holding your body together would be overwhelmed, by many orders of magnitude, by everything else going on at the time.

There are several caveats to this:

- The exact moment of the Big Bang -- the singularity -- represents the end of our current understanding. I *think* physicists tend to treat singularities as mathematical "dead-ends" that indicate that their theories are imperfect, rather than as actual physical things. Basically, we don't know.
- The "inflationary" era, proposed to come directly after the singularity, was a tiny instant before particles existed, in which space rapidly (!!!) and spontaneously expanded. All things being equal, if you traveled here, you might find the particles in your body rapidly distributed over many billions of light years, as the space *inside* you expands. (I don't know what effect your body might have on the inflationary process itself though.)
- The "particle soup" that formed after the inflationary era (though the universe was still expanding) was hot and dense on a level that just has no comparison to anything else.

  If you materialised here without displacing anything, then the particle soup would be inside you, and you'd immediately become just an infinitesimal impurity in the material.

Comment: Considering the scale of the universe at the time, your presence in the highly-ordered and homogenous primordial conditions would undoubtedly have an enormous impact on future cosmographic evolution. You'd leave a "footprint" in the structure of galactic clusters and background radiation visible across the observable universe.

Comment: could be the answer to baryon asymmetry!